# CastleProject Monorail 2.0 compatible with .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, castle-monorail

I just saw castleproject.org has released the 2.0 version of monorail in January 2010 (we are still using the 1.0RC3).

Is this version (still) compatible with .NET 2.0 (or Visual Studio 2005), and if it does will I face any problems upgrading a current web application from 1.0RC3 to 2.0?

Source code changes to monorail 2.0 and / or contributions, is that still .NET 2.0 compatible? (The trunk version was .NET 3.0 a while ago I think). Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you'd have .NET 3.5 *runtime* installed, you could write .NET 2.0 applications and reference MonoRail 2.0

I also think that having the latest service packs for .net 2.0 installed should be enough.

I'm not sure though.

I would, however, recommend that you move to VS2008, as VS2005 is simply old.

As for the actual changed in your app from 1.0RC3 to 2.0 - it depends on the level of usage you had. The more extension points you hooked into, the more adjustments you'd need. It really depends on your specific case. However, from my experience upgrading more than a few applications from MR 1 to MR 2, including very complex ones with deep integrations onto Monorail's core, the longest and toughest took two work days. I'd suggest you will consult with monorail's usergroup, and optionally get a consultant experienced with MR for a day or two.

Comment: The upgrade notes on the Monorail site are still marked TODO:. Can you suggest any particular issues to watch out for in an upgrade?